# Does memory tables have better insert performance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I want to run a task that generates a lot of inserts that cannot be easily bulked. Will it be faster to do all those inserts into a memory table and then dump the result to a regular InnoDB?

Comment: Best way to find out: Try it on your RDS instance. Each type has different performance characteristics.

Comment: No https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html